# How to implement connection management?

Tags: java, singleton, database-connection, static-methods

I need to create a class that handles connection methods. But I read online different ways to implement this.There are

1. Singleton
2. static method

1) Singleton like this example:

```
public SingletonHome{
private static SingletomHome s=null;

private SingletonHome(){
}
public static SingletongHome getInstance(){
//return instance s
}

public Connection getConnection(){
//return connection;
}
}
```

2) Use static method

```
 public class Example{

    public static Connection getConnection(){
    //return connection;
        }
    }
```

Who is the best solution in an enviroment that uses connection pool, I get connection from the connection pool and after I need to handles these.Anyone can help me?

Comment: Requests for best, are asking for opinions, they don't work well on SO Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: *static* methods like that, are "singletons", as all calls come together on that single class. From that point of view, you are better of using a singleton. But then use a java enum for that. Beyond that: dont implement your own connection pool. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @GhostCat I don't wanna implement a connection pool. I want to handles the connection that I get from connection pool, So I use the singleton?

Answer (score 0):

These two ways are not designed to be switched.
Suppose you need to change to another implementation, with `Example.getConnection()` or `SingletonHome.getInstance().getConnection()` you are stuck.
Besides these classes are not straight testable either.
You should really introduce an interface that defines operations required for a connection management.
And if your environment allows that, you should favor dependency injection to define and inject your singleton over the classical singleton pattern : it provides a lower coupling for clients.

Note that reinventing the wheel is never a good idea either and is never free bugs :  libraries that handle for you the database connection management/pooling exist : commons-dbcp, HikariCP and others... You could probably not do better than these.

Comment: I mean that I get the connection from a connection pool, I don't know implement a connection pool! I need to handle the connection that I get cfrom the connection pool!dd

Answer (score 0):

Use Pooling mechanism instead of these ways

Comment: I mean that I get the connection from a connection pool, I don't know implement a connection pool!